# Java's process builder vs Node.js' child process for running shell script

Tags: java, node.js

I have some shell scripts in a remote linux machine. I want to execute those  scripts on pressing html buttons.

I have already written the HTML and completed the back-end using java servlet. All I have to do now is to run a server (express or servlet) in my remote machine and pass some arguments to the remote machine using an HTTP GET from my local machine.(Note: Both machines are in the same network).

I just want to know whether there are any drawbacks in using Java's process builder over Node.js' child process library and vice versa.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So please [edit] your post, list your requirements and ask for software meeting those, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)